# Hiding a view inside stackview still keeps constraints active

Tags: swift, uistackview

This code can be copy paste inside a newly created project:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = createLabel()
        let imageView = createImageView()
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, label])

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5

        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (_) in
            imageView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func createLabel() -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)

        label.text = "Some Text"
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        label.backgroundColor = .green

        return label
    }

    func createImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.backgroundColor = .red
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        return imageView
    }
}
```

It is a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` inside a `UIStackView`. When I hide the `UIImageView`, I see that the `UIStackView` correctly adapts itselfs to the `UILabel's` height. However, the `UIStackView` does not adapts itself to the width of the `UILabel`.

How can I make the `UIStackView` resize itself to it's only visible views/`UILabel`? I made a variabele constraint for the `UIImageView`'s height anchor constant and turning that off when hiding the `UIImageView`, but than the `UILabel` disappears for some odd reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add stackview [alignment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616243-alignment)

> This property determines how the stack view lays out its arranged
>   views perpendicularly to its axis. The default value is
>   UIStackView.Alignment.fill.

```
stackView.alignment = .leading
```

Stackview resizes itself to it's only visible UILabel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Distribution to `Fill Equally` in the `UIStackView`'s Attribute Inspector and the `Alignment` to `Fill` or to `center` as you like it to be.